# Is the use of 'consequent' appropriate in this phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests

The phrase:

> ...using support vector methods to determine the function and
>   **consequent** structure of our dataset...

For some context, "support vector methods" determine a function for a dataset. Using this function, we can get an idea of the structure / shape of a dataset. The above sentence intends to capture this meaning succinctly.

Is the use of "consequent" appropriate in this phrase? Are there any other words that would fit this phrase for future reference?

Answer (score 1):

Without optimal contextual clarity, I think “resulting” or “corresponding” is a safer route.

Comment: **Why** is it a safer route?